# Can I Know User Is Logged in or Not?

Tags: support, comments, users

I want to know if a user is online at a given time or not. So that commenting on a question or answer would be effective.

Because the user profile only shows that the user was last seen : (Ex:30 minutes ago) but he/she may be online now.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Q&A format is not meant for rapid discussions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you know? No.

But leave them a comment (using their @name if applicable) and they'll get a notification when they are online.